# exception escapes the try block

Tags: android, multithreading, exception

This is a crash report from my developer console, which means that the crash have occured and is sent to google:

```
Android 4.2
Report 1 of 1
```

error:

```
java.lang.InterruptedException: 
      at java.lang.VMThread.sleep (VMThread.java)
      at java.lang.Thread.sleep (Thread.java:1010)
      at java.lang.Thread.sleep (Thread.java:992)
      at xyz.Draw_movingpool (xyz.java:4677)
      at xyz.phone_turn_backgammon (xyz.java:13341)
      at xyz.Update (xyz.java:1786)
      at xyz.run (MainThread.java:30)
```

This is the source code:

```
long sleepTime = 30-((System.nanoTime()-beforeTime)/1000000L);
    try {
        if(sleepTime>0){
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime); //line:4677
        }
    }catch(InterruptedException e){ break;}
```

Can someone explain to me how the exception escaped the try block?

```
Android Studio 3.1.2
Build sdk 27
JAVA 1_7
```

Comment: What is `beforeTime`? I think your `sleepTime ` is less then 0

Comment: beforeTime = System.nanoTime(); 30 lines above  . It is the start time for each loop. There is a check for that if(sleepTime>0){

Comment: For me it doesn't matter what is the cause of the exception. I want to know how It escaped the catch of its own class

Comment: Is this main thread or background?

Comment: It is a game loop thread not the uithread

Comment: Is it possible that some package you imported defines its  own `InterruptedException`? That would be evil, but what happens if you explicitly write `java.lang.InterruptedException` in your `catch` spec instead?